# Confused with raspberry pi ros setup. It seems like I have 3 instalations. Ros Noetic

Tags: ros, filesystem, rasbperrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So i'm working on a Project where I use an Raspberry Pi. As I need Python3 i installed Ros Noetic with this tutorial: [https://varhowto.com/install-ros-noetic-raspberry-pi-4]

After building It I have kind of 2 installations. I have the one in `opt/ros/noetic` but also one in `ros_catkin_ws_src`.
In my ros_catkin_ws/src there the same files as in opt. Even the "genpy" "rosconsole" etc.
To source my environment I had to use `source/devel_isolated/setup.bash`. I tested ros with only this setup. It worked fine I was able to launch the roscore and communicate with my Ros on my main Ubuntu Laptop.

Then I tried to create my own package. As my Raspberry was crashing everytime I used catkin_ make (it would install every standard Ros package again), I build my package with `catkin_make -DCATKIN_WHITELIST_PACKAGES="ranger_bot"`. Now I have 2 Ros in my Workspace. I have following: build, build_isolated, devel, devel_isolated, src. The not isolated ones wheren't there before.

Then following appears:
I source from my `devel_isolated/setup.bash`:
Roscore works, but I can't find my package. Roscd or Rosrun don't work.

I source from my `~/opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash`:
Roscore works, but I can't find my package. Roscd or Rosrun don't work.

I source from my `devel/setup.bash`:
I am able to find my package. I can use roscd ranger_bot. But if I'm trying to run the core it won't Work.

If someone could explain to me why I have this weird Filesystem. How to use it Properly or how to fix it?

Oky I found something that works: If I use `sudo src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install-space /opt/ros/noetic -j1 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3`
Now I can find my build package. But I'm still completly confuses what my file-system is.

But now I have my package in /opt/ros/noetic/share So i have to put my code into that src folder

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360944/confused-with-raspberry-pi-ros-setup.-it-seems-like-i-have-3-instalations.-ros-noetic/) by [Tobmei](https://answers.ros.org/users/51314/tobmei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2020-09-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have no clue what exactly is going on in my ros_catkin_ws (which was build during the instalation from this website)
I just made a completly new workspace and simply used catkin_make and it worked perfectly.  I also just build my first own package without problems.
I think I'm just going to ignore that Workspace and gonna use my own. I hope that should do it

---

Originally posted by [Tobmei](https://answers.ros.org/users/51314/tobmei/) with karma: 26 on 2020-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0